# Is there an easy way to rename a released TF Provider?

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

Context: we released a TF Provider and want to rename on Registry:

```
https://github.com/fooorg/terraform-provider-foobar -> https://github.com/fooorg/terraform-provider-foo
```

and hopefully have some migration guides that will help our users to migrate their existing state created by `foobar` provider to a new TF state accepted by `foo` provider (let's say the only migration difference is renaming a single resource from `foobar_user` to `foo_user` -- seems like this guide [covers](https://www.terraform.io/plugin/sdkv2/best-practices/deprecations#provider-data-source-or-resource-rename) that scenario).

There're multiple guides regarding resource renaming ([1](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/1.43.0/docs/guides/migrating-between-renamed-resources), [2](https://www.terraform.io/plugin/sdkv2/best-practices/deprecations#provider-data-source-or-resource-rename)) but I didn't find one for renaming the whole provider.

There's a manual way to run a replace command on a TF state manually but it's pretty risky so it's not desired:

```
terraform state replace-provider [options] FROM_PROVIDER_FQN TO_PROVIDER_FQN
```

Comment: When you ask about "renaming" the provider, do you mean within your config, the state, the Terraform registry, etc.?

Comment: Everything: starting from registry: `https://github.com/fooorg/terraform-provider-foobar` -> `https://github.com/fooorg/terraform-provider-foo` and hopefully migrations guide that will help users to migrate their existing state (created by `foobar` provider) to a new state that will be accepted by a new (`foo`) provider.

Comment: @MattSchuchard see my updated comment.

Comment: I am not sure what else there is to say here. You already have the resource rename covered, and the `replace-provider` subcommand covers the state. The only part you do not already have a solution for is that you will need to recreate the provider in the registry and rename the git `<org/repo>`, and then somehow inform users to migrate to the renamed provider.

Comment: @MattSchuchard it is safe to rename the git repo or it's better to create a new one (assuming existing users still wanna browse old docs / download existing binaries of `foobar` provider)

Comment: Renaming the git repo will impact everyone who has a local repo that is configured to use the current repo as a remote. They will all need to reconfigure their remote if you rename the repo. Creating a new remote would be potentially catastrophic for WIP, but I leave that to a git master.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I don't think there're a lot of users who contribute to that repo, I'm asking from TF user standpoint: will all of their old binaries continue to work / be available to download (as well as old docs on Registry under `foobar` old name vs new `foo`)?

Comment: for example, let's assume we rename repository terraform-provider-aws (of `aws` TF Provider) to `terraform-provider-awsfoo`, will https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/4.9.0/docs continue to work? What about all the users who use `4.9.0` binary of AWS TF Provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terraform treats each distinct provider source address as an entirely unrelated provider, so there won't be any automatic migration path from your old name to your new name.

The best you can do, I think, is what you already tried: publishing the same provider at the new name in the registry and then document a manual migration process that involves using [the `terraform state replace-provider` command](https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/state/replace-provider) to replace references to the old address with references to the new address in the state file.

If that isn't acceptable then I think you'll need to just accept the current name of the provider as the final name for the provider, and not rename it at all.